# How change font text to SVG path

Tags: go, svg

I have JSON input.

```
{
  "text": "Change me to svg path",
  "font": "Lato-Bold"
}
```

Expected output looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/q2rupnc3/

```
 <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="400" width="800">
        <path d="M41.54 58.79L41.54 58.79Q42.34 58.79 42.95 59.40L42.95 59.40L46.76 63.54Q43.60 67.46 38.97 69.55Q34.34 71.64 27.86 71.64L27.86 71.64Q22.07 71.64 17.44 69.66Q12.82 67.68 9.54 64.15Q6.26 60.62 4.52 55.73Q2.77 50.83 2.77 45.04L2.77 45.04Q2.77 39.17 4.64 34.29Q6.52 29.41 9.92 25.88Q13.32 22.36 18.04 20.39Q22.75 18.43 28.48 18.43L28.48 18.43Q34.16 18.43 38.57 20.30Q42.98 22.18 46.08 25.20L46.08 25.20L42.84 29.70Q42.55 30.13 42.10 30.46Q41.65 30.78 40.86 30.78L40.86 30.78Q40.32 30.78 39.74 30.47Q39.17 30.17 38.48 29.72Q37.80 29.27 36.90 28.73Q36.00 28.19 34.81 27.74Q33.62 27.29 32.06 26.98Q30.49 26.68 28.44 26.68L28.44 26.68Q24.95 26.68 22.05 27.92Q19.15 29.16 17.06 31.52Q14.98 33.88 13.82 37.28Q12.67 40.68 12.67 45.04L12.67 45.04Q12.67 49.43 13.91 52.85Q15.16 56.27 17.28 58.61Q19.40 60.95 22.28 62.19Q25.16 63.43 28.48 63.43L28.48 63.43Q30.46 63.43 32.06 63.22Q33.66 63.00 35.01 62.53Q36.36 62.06 37.57 61.33Q38.77 60.59 39.96 59.51L39.96 59.51Q40.32 59.18 40.72 58.99Q41.11 58.79 41.54 58.79ZM60.91 17.57L60.91 38.09Q63.07 36.07 65.66 34.81Q68.26 33.55 71.75 33.55L71.75 33.55Q74.77 33.55 77.11 34.58Q79.45 35.60 81.02 37.46Q82.58 39.31 83.39 41.89Q84.20 44.46 84.20 47.56L84.20 47.56L84.20 71.06L75.31 71.06L75.31 47.56Q75.31 44.17 73.76 42.32Q72.22 40.46 69.05 40.46L69.05 40.46Q66.74 40.46 64.73 41.51Q62.71 42.55 60.91 44.35L60.91 44.35L60.91 71.06L52.02 71.06L52.02 17.57L60.91 17.57ZM112.14 61.52L112.14 55.30Q108.29 55.48 105.66 55.96Q103.03 56.45 101.45 57.20Q99.86 57.96 99.18 58.97Q98.50 59.98 98.50 61.16L98.50 61.16Q98.50 63.50 99.88 64.51Q101.27 65.52 103.50 65.52L103.50 65.52Q106.24 65.52 108.23 64.53Q110.23 63.54 112.14 61.52L112.14 61.52ZM93.35 42.12L91.76 39.28Q98.14 33.44 107.10 33.44L107.10 33.44Q110.34 33.44 112.90 34.51Q115.45 35.57 117.22 37.46Q118.98 39.35 119.90 41.98Q120.82 44.60 120.82 47.74L120.82 47.74L120.82 71.06L116.78 71.06Q115.52 71.06 114.84 70.69Q114.16 70.31 113.76 69.16L113.76 69.16L112.97 66.49Q111.56 67.75 110.23 68.71Q108.90 69.66 107.46 70.31Q106.02 70.96 104.38 71.30Q102.74 71.64 100.76 71.64L100.76 71.64Q98.42 71.64 96.44 71.01Q94.46 70.38 93.02 69.12Q91.58 67.86 90.79 65.99Q90.00 64.12 90.00 61.63L90.00 61.63Q90.00 60.23 90.47 58.84Q90.94 57.46 92.00 56.20Q93.06 54.94 94.75 53.82Q96.44 52.70 98.91 51.88Q101.38 51.05 104.65 50.53Q107.93 50.00 112.14 49.90L112.14 49.90L112.14 47.74Q112.14 44.03 110.56 42.25Q108.97 40.46 105.98 40.46L105.98 40.46Q103.82 40.46 102.40 40.97Q100.98 41.47 99.90 42.10Q98.82 42.73 97.94 43.24Q97.06 43.74 95.98 43.74L95.98 43.74Q95.04 43.74 94.39 43.25Q93.74 42.77 93.35 42.12L93.35 42.12ZM136.87 35.75L137.48 38.66Q138.60 37.55 139.84 36.59Q141.08 35.64 142.47 34.97Q143.86 34.31 145.44 33.93Q147.02 33.55 148.90 33.55L148.90 33.55Q151.92 33.55 154.26 34.58Q156.60 35.60 158.17 37.46Q159.73 39.31 160.54 41.89Q161.35 44.46 161.35 47.56L161.35 47.56L161.35 71.06L152.46 71.06L152.46 47.56Q152.46 44.17 150.91 42.32Q149.36 40.46 146.20 40.46L146.20 40.46Q143.89 40.46 141.88 41.51Q139.86 42.55 138.06 44.35L138.06 44.35L138.06 71.06L129.17 71.06L129.17 34.13L134.60 34.13Q136.33 34.13 136.87 35.75L136.87 35.75ZM183.28 51.70L183.28 51.70Q184.93 51.70 186.16 51.25Q187.38 50.80 188.19 50.00Q189.00 49.21 189.41 48.10Q189.83 46.98 189.83 45.65L189.83 45.65Q189.83 42.91 188.19 41.31Q186.55 39.71 183.28 39.71L183.28 39.71Q180.00 39.71 178.36 41.31Q176.72 42.91 176.72 45.65L176.72 45.65Q176.72 46.94 177.14 48.06Q177.55 49.18 178.36 49.99Q179.17 50.80 180.41 51.25Q181.66 51.70 183.28 51.70ZM193.32 72.72L193.32 72.72Q193.32 71.64 192.67 70.96Q192.02 70.27 190.91 69.89Q189.79 69.52 188.30 69.34Q186.80 69.16 185.13 69.07Q183.46 68.98 181.67 68.90Q179.89 68.83 178.20 68.62L178.20 68.62Q176.72 69.44 175.81 70.56Q174.89 71.68 174.89 73.15L174.89 73.15Q174.89 74.12 175.37 74.97Q175.86 75.82 176.92 76.43Q177.98 77.04 179.68 77.38Q181.37 77.72 183.82 77.72L183.82 77.72Q186.30 77.72 188.10 77.35Q189.90 76.97 191.07 76.30Q192.24 75.64 192.78 74.72Q193.32 73.80 193.32 72.72ZM191.56 35.39L202.18 35.39L202.18 38.70Q202.18 40.28 200.27 40.64L200.27 40.64L196.96 41.26Q197.71 43.16 197.71 45.43L197.71 45.43Q197.71 48.17 196.61 50.38Q195.52 52.60 193.57 54.14Q191.63 55.69 188.98 56.54Q186.34 57.38 183.28 57.38L183.28 57.38Q182.20 57.38 181.19 57.28Q180.18 57.17 179.21 56.99L179.21 56.99Q177.48 58.03 177.48 59.33L177.48 59.33Q177.48 60.44 178.51 60.97Q179.53 61.49 181.22 61.70Q182.92 61.92 185.08 61.97Q187.24 62.03 189.50 62.21Q191.77 62.39 193.93 62.84Q196.09 63.29 197.78 64.26Q199.48 65.23 200.50 66.91Q201.53 68.58 201.53 71.21L201.53 71.21Q201.53 73.66 200.32 75.96Q199.12 78.26 196.83 80.06Q194.54 81.86 191.21 82.96Q187.88 84.06 183.64 84.06L183.64 84.06Q179.46 84.06 176.36 83.25Q173.27 82.44 171.22 81.09Q169.16 79.74 168.16 77.98Q167.15 76.21 167.15 74.30L167.15 74.30Q167.15 71.71 168.71 69.97Q170.28 68.22 173.02 67.18L173.02 67.18Q171.54 66.42 170.68 65.16Q169.81 63.90 169.81 61.85L169.81 61.85Q169.81 61.02 170.12 60.14Q170.42 59.26 171.02 58.39Q171.61 57.53 172.51 56.75Q173.41 55.98 174.64 55.37L174.64 55.37Q171.83 53.86 170.23 51.34Q168.62 48.82 168.62 45.43L168.62 45.43Q168.62 42.70 169.72 40.48Q170.82 38.27 172.78 36.70Q174.74 35.14 177.43 34.31Q180.11 33.48 183.28 33.48L183.28 33.48Q185.65 33.48 187.74 33.97Q189.83 34.45 191.56 35.39L191.56 35.39ZM214.81 48.35L231.59 48.35Q231.59 46.62 231.10 45.09Q230.62 43.56 229.64 42.41Q228.67 41.26 227.18 40.59Q225.68 39.92 223.70 39.92L223.70 39.92Q219.85 39.92 217.64 42.12Q215.42 44.32 214.81 48.35L214.81 48.35ZM237.49 53.71L214.63 53.71Q214.85 56.56 215.64 58.63Q216.43 60.70 217.73 62.05Q219.02 63.40 220.81 64.06Q222.59 64.73 224.75 64.73L224.75 64.73Q226.91 64.73 228.47 64.22Q230.04 63.72 231.21 63.11Q232.38 62.50 233.26 61.99Q234.14 61.49 234.97 61.49L234.97 61.49Q236.09 61.49 236.63 62.32L236.63 62.32L239.18 65.56Q237.71 67.28 235.87 68.45Q234.04 69.62 232.04 70.33Q230.04 71.03 227.97 71.32Q225.90 71.60 223.96 71.60L223.96 71.60Q220.10 71.60 216.79 70.33Q213.48 69.05 211.03 66.55Q208.58 64.04 207.18 60.35Q205.78 56.66 205.78 51.80L205.78 51.80Q205.78 48.02 207.00 44.69Q208.22 41.36 210.51 38.90Q212.80 36.43 216.09 34.99Q219.38 33.55 223.52 33.55L223.52 33.55Q227.02 33.55 229.97 34.67Q232.92 35.78 235.04 37.93Q237.17 40.07 238.37 43.18Q239.58 46.30 239.58 50.29L239.58 50.29Q239.58 52.31 239.15 53.01Q238.72 53.71 237.49 53.71L237.49 53.71ZM272.63 71.06L263.74 71.06L263.74 34.13L269.17 34.13Q270.90 34.13 271.44 35.75L271.44 35.75L272.02 38.48Q272.99 37.40 274.05 36.50Q275.11 35.60 276.32 34.96Q277.52 34.31 278.91 33.93Q280.30 33.55 281.95 33.55L281.95 33.55Q285.44 33.55 287.69 35.44Q289.94 37.33 291.06 40.46L291.06 40.46Q291.92 38.63 293.22 37.31Q294.52 36 296.06 35.17Q297.61 34.34 299.36 33.95Q301.10 33.55 302.87 33.55L302.87 33.55Q305.93 33.55 308.30 34.49Q310.68 35.42 312.30 37.22Q313.92 39.02 314.77 41.62Q315.61 44.21 315.61 47.56L315.61 47.56L315.61 71.06L306.72 71.06L306.72 47.56Q306.72 44.03 305.17 42.25Q303.62 40.46 300.64 40.46L300.64 40.46Q299.27 40.46 298.10 40.93Q296.93 41.40 296.05 42.28Q295.16 43.16 294.66 44.50Q294.16 45.83 294.16 47.56L294.16 47.56L294.16 71.06L285.23 71.06L285.23 47.56Q285.23 43.85 283.73 42.16Q282.24 40.46 279.36 40.46L279.36 40.46Q277.42 40.46 275.74 41.42Q274.07 42.37 272.63 44.03L272.63 44.03L272.63 71.06ZM331.06 48.35L347.83 48.35Q347.83 46.62 347.35 45.09Q346.86 43.56 345.89 42.41Q344.92 41.26 343.42 40.59Q341.93 39.92 339.95 39.92L339.95 39.92Q336.10 39.92 333.88 42.12Q331.67 44.32 331.06 48.35L331.06 48.35ZM353.74 53.71L330.88 53.71Q331.09 56.56 331.88 58.63Q332.68 60.70 333.97 62.05Q335.27 63.40 337.05 64.06Q338.83 64.73 340.99 64.73L340.99 64.73Q343.15 64.73 344.72 64.22Q346.28 63.72 347.45 63.11Q348.62 62.50 349.51 61.99Q350.39 61.49 351.22 61.49L351.22 61.49Q352.33 61.49 352.87 62.32L352.87 62.32L355.43 65.56Q353.95 67.28 352.12 68.45Q350.28 69.62 348.28 70.33Q346.28 71.03 344.21 71.32Q342.14 71.60 340.20 71.60L340.20 71.60Q336.35 71.60 333.04 70.33Q329.72 69.05 327.28 66.55Q324.83 64.04 323.42 60.35Q322.02 56.66 322.02 51.80L322.02 51.80Q322.02 48.02 323.24 44.69Q324.47 41.36 326.75 38.90Q329.04 36.43 332.33 34.99Q335.63 33.55 339.77 33.55L339.77 33.55Q343.26 33.55 346.21 34.67Q349.16 35.78 351.29 37.93Q353.41 40.07 354.62 43.18Q355.82 46.30 355.82 50.29L355.82 50.29Q355.82 52.31 355.39 53.01Q354.96 53.71 353.74 53.71L353.74 53.71ZM392.29 71.64L392.29 71.64Q387.47 71.64 384.89 68.92Q382.32 66.20 382.32 61.42L382.32 61.42L382.32 40.79L378.54 40.79Q377.82 40.79 377.32 40.32Q376.81 39.85 376.81 38.92L376.81 38.92L376.81 35.39L382.75 34.42L384.62 24.34Q384.80 23.62 385.31 23.22Q385.81 22.82 386.60 22.82L386.60 22.82L391.21 22.82L391.21 34.45L401.08 34.45L401.08 40.79L391.21 40.79L391.21 60.80Q391.21 62.53 392.06 63.50Q392.90 64.48 394.38 64.48L394.38 64.48Q395.21 64.48 395.77 64.28Q396.32 64.08 396.74 63.86Q397.15 63.65 397.48 63.45Q397.80 63.25 398.12 63.25L398.12 63.25Q398.52 63.25 398.77 63.45Q399.02 63.65 399.31 64.04L399.31 64.04L401.98 68.36Q400.03 69.98 397.51 70.81Q394.99 71.64 392.29 71.64ZM423.11 33.55L423.11 33.55Q427.21 33.55 430.58 34.88Q433.94 36.22 436.34 38.66Q438.73 41.11 440.03 44.64Q441.32 48.17 441.32 52.52L441.32 52.52Q441.32 56.92 440.03 60.44Q438.73 63.97 436.34 66.46Q433.94 68.94 430.58 70.27Q427.21 71.60 423.11 71.60L423.11 71.60Q418.97 71.60 415.58 70.27Q412.20 68.94 409.81 66.46Q407.41 63.97 406.10 60.44Q404.78 56.92 404.78 52.52L404.78 52.52Q404.78 48.17 406.10 44.64Q407.41 41.11 409.81 38.66Q412.20 36.22 415.58 34.88Q418.97 33.55 423.11 33.55ZM423.11 64.76L423.11 64.76Q427.72 64.76 429.93 61.67Q432.14 58.57 432.14 52.60L432.14 52.60Q432.14 46.62 429.93 43.49Q427.72 40.36 423.11 40.36L423.11 40.36Q418.43 40.36 416.18 43.51Q413.93 46.66 413.93 52.60L413.93 52.60Q413.93 58.54 416.18 61.65Q418.43 64.76 423.11 64.76ZM490.18 38.12L488.16 41.33Q487.80 41.90 487.40 42.14Q487.01 42.37 486.40 42.37L486.40 42.37Q485.75 42.37 485.01 42.01Q484.27 41.65 483.30 41.20Q482.33 40.75 481.09 40.39Q479.84 40.03 478.15 40.03L478.15 40.03Q475.52 40.03 474.03 41.15Q472.54 42.26 472.54 44.06L472.54 44.06Q472.54 45.25 473.31 46.06Q474.08 46.87 475.36 47.48Q476.64 48.10 478.26 48.58Q479.88 49.07 481.55 49.64Q483.23 50.22 484.85 50.96Q486.47 51.70 487.75 52.83Q489.02 53.96 489.80 55.55Q490.57 57.13 490.57 59.36L490.57 59.36Q490.57 62.03 489.62 64.28Q488.66 66.53 486.79 68.17Q484.92 69.80 482.17 70.72Q479.41 71.64 475.81 71.64L475.81 71.64Q473.90 71.64 472.09 71.30Q470.27 70.96 468.59 70.34Q466.92 69.73 465.50 68.90Q464.08 68.08 463.00 67.10L463.00 67.10L465.05 63.72Q465.44 63.11 465.98 62.78Q466.52 62.46 467.35 62.46L467.35 62.46Q468.18 62.46 468.92 62.93Q469.66 63.40 470.63 63.94Q471.60 64.48 472.91 64.94Q474.23 65.41 476.24 65.41L476.24 65.41Q477.83 65.41 478.96 65.03Q480.10 64.66 480.83 64.04Q481.57 63.43 481.91 62.62Q482.26 61.81 482.26 60.95L482.26 60.95Q482.26 59.65 481.48 58.82Q480.71 58.00 479.43 57.38Q478.15 56.77 476.51 56.29Q474.88 55.80 473.17 55.22Q471.46 54.65 469.82 53.87Q468.18 53.10 466.90 51.91Q465.62 50.72 464.85 49.00Q464.08 47.27 464.08 44.82L464.08 44.82Q464.08 42.55 464.98 40.50Q465.88 38.45 467.62 36.92Q469.37 35.39 471.98 34.47Q474.59 33.55 478.01 33.55L478.01 33.55Q481.82 33.55 484.96 34.81Q488.09 36.07 490.18 38.12L490.18 38.12ZM523.55 34.13L530.57 34.13L515.92 71.06L507.85 71.06L493.20 34.13L500.54 34.13Q501.55 34.13 502.22 34.60Q502.88 35.06 503.10 35.78L503.10 35.78L510.23 55.51Q510.80 57.24 511.24 58.90Q511.67 60.55 511.99 62.21L511.99 62.21Q512.35 60.55 512.78 58.90Q513.22 57.24 513.83 55.51L513.83 55.51L521.10 35.78Q521.35 35.06 522.00 34.60Q522.65 34.13 523.55 34.13L523.55 34.13ZM548.78 51.70L548.78 51.70Q550.44 51.70 551.66 51.25Q552.89 50.80 553.70 50.00Q554.51 49.21 554.92 48.10Q555.34 46.98 555.34 45.65L555.34 45.65Q555.34 42.91 553.70 41.31Q552.06 39.71 548.78 39.71L548.78 39.71Q545.51 39.71 543.87 41.31Q542.23 42.91 542.23 45.65L542.23 45.65Q542.23 46.94 542.65 48.06Q543.06 49.18 543.87 49.99Q544.68 50.80 545.92 51.25Q547.16 51.70 548.78 51.70ZM558.83 72.72L558.83 72.72Q558.83 71.64 558.18 70.96Q557.53 70.27 556.42 69.89Q555.30 69.52 553.81 69.34Q552.31 69.16 550.64 69.07Q548.96 68.98 547.18 68.90Q545.40 68.83 543.71 68.62L543.71 68.62Q542.23 69.44 541.31 70.56Q540.40 71.68 540.40 73.15L540.40 73.15Q540.40 74.12 540.88 74.97Q541.37 75.82 542.43 76.43Q543.49 77.04 545.18 77.38Q546.88 77.72 549.32 77.72L549.32 77.72Q551.81 77.72 553.61 77.35Q555.41 76.97 556.58 76.30Q557.75 75.64 558.29 74.72Q558.83 73.80 558.83 72.72ZM557.06 35.39L567.68 35.39L567.68 38.70Q567.68 40.28 565.78 40.64L565.78 40.64L562.46 41.26Q563.22 43.16 563.22 45.43L563.22 45.43Q563.22 48.17 562.12 50.38Q561.02 52.60 559.08 54.14Q557.14 55.69 554.49 56.54Q551.84 57.38 548.78 57.38L548.78 57.38Q547.70 57.38 546.70 57.28Q545.69 57.17 544.72 56.99L544.72 56.99Q542.99 58.03 542.99 59.33L542.99 59.33Q542.99 60.44 544.01 60.97Q545.04 61.49 546.73 61.70Q548.42 61.92 550.58 61.97Q552.74 62.03 555.01 62.21Q557.28 62.39 559.44 62.84Q561.60 63.29 563.29 64.26Q564.98 65.23 566.01 66.91Q567.04 68.58 567.04 71.21L567.04 71.21Q567.04 73.66 565.83 75.96Q564.62 78.26 562.34 80.06Q560.05 81.86 556.72 82.96Q553.39 84.06 549.14 84.06L549.14 84.06Q544.97 84.06 541.87 83.25Q538.78 82.44 536.72 81.09Q534.67 79.74 533.66 77.98Q532.66 76.21 532.66 74.30L532.66 74.30Q532.66 71.71 534.22 69.97Q535.79 68.22 538.52 67.18L538.52 67.18Q537.05 66.42 536.18 65.16Q535.32 63.90 535.32 61.85L535.32 61.85Q535.32 61.02 535.63 60.14Q535.93 59.26 536.53 58.39Q537.12 57.53 538.02 56.75Q538.92 55.98 540.14 55.37L540.14 55.37Q537.34 53.86 535.73 51.34Q534.13 48.82 534.13 45.43L534.13 45.43Q534.13 42.70 535.23 40.48Q536.33 38.27 538.29 36.70Q540.25 35.14 542.93 34.31Q545.62 33.48 548.78 33.48L548.78 33.48Q551.16 33.48 553.25 33.97Q555.34 34.45 557.06 35.39L557.06 35.39ZM599.69 44.93L599.69 61.49Q601.20 63.32 602.98 64.08Q604.76 64.84 606.85 64.84L606.85 64.84Q608.87 64.84 610.49 64.08Q612.11 63.32 613.24 61.78Q614.38 60.23 614.99 57.87Q615.60 55.51 615.60 52.31L615.60 52.31Q615.60 49.07 615.08 46.82Q614.56 44.57 613.58 43.16Q612.61 41.76 611.23 41.11Q609.84 40.46 608.08 40.46L608.08 40.46Q605.30 40.46 603.36 41.63Q601.42 42.80 599.69 44.93L599.69 44.93ZM598.50 35.75L599.22 39.17Q601.49 36.61 604.37 35.03Q607.25 33.44 611.14 33.44L611.14 33.44Q614.16 33.44 616.66 34.70Q619.16 35.96 620.98 38.36Q622.80 40.75 623.79 44.26Q624.78 47.77 624.78 52.31L624.78 52.31Q624.78 56.45 623.66 59.98Q622.55 63.50 620.48 66.10Q618.41 68.69 615.47 70.15Q612.54 71.60 608.90 71.60L608.90 71.60Q605.81 71.60 603.61 70.65Q601.42 69.70 599.69 68.00L599.69 68.00L599.69 83.12L590.80 83.12L590.80 34.13L596.23 34.13Q597.96 34.13 598.50 35.75L598.50 35.75ZM651.20 61.52L651.20 55.30Q647.35 55.48 644.72 55.96Q642.10 56.45 640.51 57.20Q638.93 57.96 638.24 58.97Q637.56 59.98 637.56 61.16L637.56 61.16Q637.56 63.50 638.95 64.51Q640.33 65.52 642.56 65.52L642.56 65.52Q645.30 65.52 647.30 64.53Q649.30 63.54 651.20 61.52L651.20 61.52ZM632.41 42.12L630.83 39.28Q637.20 33.44 646.16 33.44L646.16 33.44Q649.40 33.44 651.96 34.51Q654.52 35.57 656.28 37.46Q658.04 39.35 658.96 41.98Q659.88 44.60 659.88 47.74L659.88 47.74L659.88 71.06L655.85 71.06Q654.59 71.06 653.90 70.69Q653.22 70.31 652.82 69.16L652.82 69.16L652.03 66.49Q650.63 67.75 649.30 68.71Q647.96 69.66 646.52 70.31Q645.08 70.96 643.45 71.30Q641.81 71.64 639.83 71.64L639.83 71.64Q637.49 71.64 635.51 71.01Q633.53 70.38 632.09 69.12Q630.65 67.86 629.86 65.99Q629.06 64.12 629.06 61.63L629.06 61.63Q629.06 60.23 629.53 58.84Q630 57.46 631.06 56.20Q632.12 54.94 633.82 53.82Q635.51 52.70 637.97 51.88Q640.44 51.05 643.72 50.53Q646.99 50.00 651.20 49.90L651.20 49.90L651.20 47.74Q651.20 44.03 649.62 42.25Q648.04 40.46 645.05 40.46L645.05 40.46Q642.89 40.46 641.47 40.97Q640.04 41.47 638.96 42.10Q637.88 42.73 637.00 43.24Q636.12 43.74 635.04 43.74L635.04 43.74Q634.10 43.74 633.46 43.25Q632.81 42.77 632.41 42.12L632.41 42.12ZM680.54 71.64L680.54 71.64Q675.72 71.64 673.15 68.92Q670.57 66.20 670.57 61.42L670.57 61.42L670.57 40.79L666.79 40.79Q666.07 40.79 665.57 40.32Q665.06 39.85 665.06 38.92L665.06 38.92L665.06 35.39L671.00 34.42L672.88 24.34Q673.06 23.62 673.56 23.22Q674.06 22.82 674.86 22.82L674.86 22.82L679.46 22.82L679.46 34.45L689.33 34.45L689.33 40.79L679.46 40.79L679.46 60.80Q679.46 62.53 680.31 63.50Q681.16 64.48 682.63 64.48L682.63 64.48Q683.46 64.48 684.02 64.28Q684.58 64.08 684.99 63.86Q685.40 63.65 685.73 63.45Q686.05 63.25 686.38 63.25L686.38 63.25Q686.77 63.25 687.02 63.45Q687.28 63.65 687.56 64.04L687.56 64.04L690.23 68.36Q688.28 69.98 685.76 70.81Q683.24 71.64 680.54 71.64ZM703.91 17.57L703.91 38.09Q706.07 36.07 708.66 34.81Q711.25 33.55 714.74 33.55L714.74 33.55Q717.77 33.55 720.11 34.58Q722.45 35.60 724.01 37.46Q725.58 39.31 726.39 41.89Q727.20 44.46 727.20 47.56L727.20 47.56L727.20 71.06L718.31 71.06L718.31 47.56Q718.31 44.17 716.76 42.32Q715.21 40.46 712.04 40.46L712.04 40.46Q709.74 40.46 707.72 41.51Q705.71 42.55 703.91 44.35L703.91 44.35L703.91 71.06L695.02 71.06L695.02 17.57L703.91 17.57Z" />
    </svg>
```

I have Lato-Bold.ttf file on my device so if it will be needed I can use it. I can not use text svg tag because the svg reader only understands path. How can this be achieved with it with Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible with https://github.com/tdewolff/canvas (I'm the principal author). You can see an example at https://github.com/tdewolff/canvas/blob/master/examples/preview/main.go#L89 (result at https://github.com/tdewolff/canvas/blob/master/examples/preview/out.png) where I load a font and convert a piece of text to a vector path.

The following should work in your case (not tested) using tdewolff/canvas:

```golang
fontFamily := canvas.NewFontFamily("Lato")
if err := fontFamily.LoadFontFile("Lato-Bold.ttf", canvas.FontBold); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

face := fontFamily.Face(14.0, canvas.Black, canvas.FontBold, canvas.FontNormal)
path, err := face.ToPath("Change me to svg path")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

tpl := `<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="400" width="800">
    <path d="%s" />
</svg>`
fmt.Printf(tpl, path.ToSVG())
```